# Column truncated in TableAPI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

results displayed by the code below are truncated to 30 :

```
tableEnv.createTemporaryView("topicData", topicData);
TableConfig tableConfig = tableEnv.getConfig();
tableConfig.set("table.display.max-column-width", "1000");
tableEnv.sqlQuery("select * from topicData").execute().print();
```

As you see I am using property “table.display.max-column-width”, so my expectation was that it should show up to 1000 chars. Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [config page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/config/#table-options) there is `sql-client.display.max-column-width` for SQL Client but for table API there is no such option as `table.display.max-column-width`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was referring to documentation for unreleased version https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/config/